# User with apostrophe in email address is not added in required attendee using Office.js Office.context.mailbox.item.requiredAttendees.setAsync

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

We have developed an Office Add-In which uses **Office.js** in built function **Office.context.mailbox.item.requiredAttendees.setAsync** to add attendees in Calendar appointment.

If the user has **apostrophe** in email address e.g. user'test@abc.com then the above function is not adding it in required attendee field of Calendar appointment and doesn't give any error. Below is the code snippet.

[Adding 2 users. One with apostrophe and one without apostrophe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Edc8r.png)

[Office.context.mailbox.item.requiredAttendees.setAsync function gives succeeded response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3O85.png)

[But only one user without apostrophe in email address added to the required attendee field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZ7G9.png)

User with apostrophe in email address must be added to the required attendee field using Office.js Office.context.mailbox.item.requiredAttendees.setAsync function.

Comment: Thank you for reaching out with this issue.

Does this issue only present itself in Outlook on the Web, or do you also see it in other platforms (Windows, Mac, Android)?

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue regarding requiredAttendees.seAsync API.  It has been put on our backlog. We unfortunately have no timelines to share at this point.
Internal tracking id: 3960572